# Pandas Dataframe, How do I filter a dataframe on the date column, greater than Jan 1 of 5 years ago

Tags: pandas, date, filter

I have a dataframe in pandas that I would like to filter. How do I filter it so it only includes rows greater than January 1st of 5 years ago.

with the below code I get the error:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import datetime 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


sns.set()

df = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx", sheet_name='Seasonality')

df = df[1:]
df = df.rename(columns = {df.columns[0]: 'Date', df.columns[1]: 'WTI', df.columns[2]: 'RBOB'})
print(df)

today = date.today()
fiveYrAgo = date.today() - relativedelta(years=5)
seasStart = datetime.date(int(today.year-5),1,1)

dfSeas = df[(df['Date'] > seasStart)]
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try changing `seasStart` to a `datetime.datetime` using: `seasStart = datetime.datetime(today.year-5,1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

As per your code it seems like seasStart is a datetime.date object.

Convert that object to datetime.datetime:

```
seasStart = pd.to_datetime(seasStart)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an alternative solution:

converting the 'Date' column to datetime, then using a string to filter the dataframe for the required dates

```
df = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx", sheet_name='Seasonality')

df = df[1:]
df = df.rename(columns = {df.columns[0]: 'Date', df.columns[1]: 'WTI', df.columns[2]: 'RBOB'})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
dfColumns = list(df.columns.values)
dfColumns = dfColumns[1:]
today = date.today()

dfSeas = df[(df['Date'] > str(today.year-5) + "-1-1")].copy()
dfSeas['Year'] = dfSeas['Date'].dt.year
dfSeas['Month'] = dfSeas['Date'].dt.month
dfSeas['Week'] = dfSeas['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week
dfSeas
```